# Changing Content in Two Different Div's with Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu, that when a user selects an option, the appropriate content should be populated below the dropdown menu. This is achievable and working. However, I want the content to change in TWO sections simultaneously - one section below as mentioned before and one section to the right (as with Topic 1, Topic 2, Topic 3).

When I set the content to display below AND to the right it only displays the content to the right (as seen when selecting dropdown options Topic 1, Topic 2, Topic 3).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpBpaV

I know there is an issue because I am using id's in two separate occasions (one in a div below the dropdown and one in a div to the right of the dropdown). However, I did change the javascript from `document.getElementById` to `document.getElementByClass` and changed all the id's to classes since some are used twice. However, the JS did not render at all when I changed the HTML/JS to use classes.

Is there any insight as to why I am not able to display both content on the right and below at the same time? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<br><br><br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <!-- DROPDOWN MENU -->
            <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                <option value="0">Select Topic</option>
                <option value="1">Topic 1</option>
                <option value="2">Topic 2</option>
                <option value="3">Topic 3</option>
                <option value="4">Topic 4</option>
                <option value="5">Topic 5</option>
                <option value="6">Topic 6</option>
                <option value="7">Topic 7</option>
                <option value="8">Topic 8</option>
                <option value="9">Topic 9</option>
                <option value="10">Topic 10</option>
                <option value="11">Topic 11</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- CONTENT OFF TO THE RIGHT -->
        <div class="col-md-6" >

            <div class="content" id="1" > 
                TOPIC 1 - RIGHT
            </div>

            <div class="content" id="2">  
                TOPIC 2 - RIGHT
            </div>

            <div class="content" id="3">  
                TOPIC 3 - RIGHT
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- CONTENT BELOW FORM -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="content" id="0" style="display: block">
                     SELECT TOPIC
                </div>     
                <div class="content" id="1">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 1
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="2">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 2
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="3">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 3
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="4">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 4
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="5">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 5
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="6">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 6
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="7">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 7
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="8">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 8
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="9">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 9
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="10">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 10
                </div>

                <div class="content" id="11">
                    DISPLAYING TOPIC 11
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.content {
      display: none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function() {
                var i = 0; // 
                var topicNumber = document.getElementById(i);
                while(topicNumber) {
                    topicNumber.style.display = 'none';
                    topicNumber = document.getElementById(++i);
                }
                document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOVJPq)

The id's were made unique and the following Javascript was adjusted

```
document.getElementById('dropdown').onchange = function() {
    //Loop over all the topics to make them invisible
    var topics = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
    for (var i = 0; i < topics.length; ++i) {
        var item = topics[i];  
        item.style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("left"+(this.value)).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("right"+(this.value)).style.display = 'block';
};
```

As Roamer-1888 said, your id's *must* be unique [within your page] in order to "uniquely" identify them.

Lastly, there is also no need to use pure JS in your case seeing that you include jQuery (which you've added the same library 4 times by the way).

Comment: Perfect, THANK YOU! You are right about keeping all the id's unique.

Answer (score 0):

Div ids "1", "2" and "3" are repeated.

If you are going to address your divs by id, then the ids *must* be unique.

There are many ways to make this work. For example, make the ids unique by giving each set a prefix :

```
<div class="content" id="right1">
    TOPIC 1 - RIGHT
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
```

```
<div class="content" id="under1">
    DISPLAYING TOPIC 1
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Now, you can reliably address the "right" set and the "under" set independently.

As the question is tagged jQuery, here's a jQuery solution :

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var i = $(this).val();
    $('#right' + i).show().siblings().hide();
    $('#under' + i).show().siblings().hide();
};
```

If you want, then by all means code this in POJS but it will be many more lines.

Comment: that's the issue i mentioned. to make them the same i used classes but that didnt work. how can i use unique id's or change the JS to integrate the request to change both sections and not just one